# Why is the rotation not zero and the divergence zero in the figures below?

Tags: derivatives, vector-fields

Why is the rotation not zero and the divergence zero in figure 1 and figure 2 below?

[image] Figure 1

[image] Figure 2

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't fully understand your question. You've illustrated some vector fields $\vec V$ with those diagrams, and you want to know to know whether $\vec\nabla \times \vec V = 0$ and whether $\vec\nabla \cdot \vec V=0$?

Comment: @innisfree yes, and why the result of the dot product is zero and the result of the cross product is not zero.